# Finite language with finite models implies that a set of sentences in that language only have finitely many models?

Tags: logic

I've been trying to figure out why this is true: If $\Sigma$ is a set of sentences in a finite language which has equality, and all models of $\Sigma$ are finite, then $\Sigma$ has finitely many models, up to isomorphism. Could someone prove this?

Comment: Compactness gives you the way which should go.

Comment: Any chance you could expand on this? I am still lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: suppose $\Sigma$ had infinitely many models.

- What can you say about the set of sizes of models of $\Sigma$? *Remember that the language is finite . . .*
- Why does this give you a contradiction? *Think about what tools you have for building **infinite** models of theories . . .*

Comment: This must be an application of Lowenheim-Skolem, right? I still can't $\textit{quite}$ see what to do...

Comment: not lowenheim skolem. the tool you always want to use to go from finite to infinite is compactness.

Comment: Ah, of course. I'll think about this, thanks.

Comment: So let me see if I have this right. The argument should go, if we have infinitely many models, then the sizes of the models becomes arbitrarily large, so by compactness $\Sigma$ has an infinite model, contradiction. Is that right?